# Partial derivative with respect to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm a bit stuck on the following, and I feel like I am missing something obvious.  Suppose that $\mathbf{h}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are vectors of different lengths and that $\mathbf{W}$ is a full matrix.

How can I calculate the following partial derivative?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{W}} \tanh(\mathbf{h}^\top \tanh(\mathbf{W}^\top \mathbf{x}))
$$

My approach has been repeated applications of the chain rule, but I end up with a vector result where I should have a matrix.  Help!

Comment: You need to differentiate with respect to $W_{ij}$ for each $i,j$.  This should give you the right number of entries.  Also, it is not entirely obvious what you mean by $\tanh$ of a vector.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out using what you said here regarding $W_{ij}$. I meant a element-by-element $\tanh$ of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in matrix, rather than index, notation.

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 S &= W^TX \cr
 R &= {\rm tanh}(S) \cr
 z &= H:R = ({\rm Frobenius \,\, Product}) \cr
 f &= {\rm tanh}(z)  \cr
}$$
We know the differential of the hyperbolic function is
$$\,\,d\,{\rm tanh}(z) = [1-{\rm tanh}^2(z)]\,\,dz$$

Now successively substitute the above quantities
$$\eqalign{
 df &= (1-f^2)\,dz \cr
    &= (1-f^2)\,H:dR \cr
    &= (1-f^2)\,H:(1-R\circ R)\circ dS \cr
    &= (1-f^2)\,H\circ(1-R\circ R):dS \cr
    &= Q:dS \cr
    &= Q:dW^TX \cr
    &= Q^T:X^TdW \cr
    &= XQ^T:dW \cr
    &= \bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial W}\bigg):dW \cr
}$$
Comparing the last 2 lines, the derivative must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial W} &= XQ^T \cr
    &= (1\!-\!f^2)\,X\,(H\!-\!H\!\circ\!R\circ\!R)^T \cr
    &= (1\!-\!f^2)\,X\,\bigg(H^T\!-\!H^T\!\circ{\rm tanh}^2(X^TW)\bigg) \cr
}$$
This was derived for the case that $(H, X)$ are full matrices. But you can replace them with the vector quantities $(h, x)$ to answer the original question.